# Как запустить cmd от имени администратора и выполнить команды средствами языка c#?

Tags: c#, cmd, командная-строка

Необходимо выполнить команды `cmd` средствами языка `c#`
Запуск `cmd` необходим от имени администратора т.к команды для настройки `IIS`.

*Команды:*

```
pkgmgr /iu:IIS-FTPServer;IIS-FTPSvc;IIS-FTPExtensibility;

cd %windir%\system32\inetsrv 
set ftproot=%systemdrive%\inetpub\ftproot
set ftpsite=MyFtp1
if not exist "%ftproot%" (mkdir "%ftproot%") 
appcmd add site /name:%ftpsite% /bindings:ftp://*:21 /physicalpath:"%ftproot%" 
appcmd set config -section:system.applicationHost/sites /[name='%ftpsite%'].ftpServer.security.authentication.AnonimouseAuthentication.enabled:true 
appcmd set config -section:system.applicationHost/sites /[name='%ftpsite%'].ftpServer.security.ssl.controlChannelPolicy:"SslAllow" 
appcmd set config -section:system.applicationHost/sites /[name='%ftpsite%'].ftpServer.security.ssl.dataChannelPolicy:"SslAllow" 
appcmd set config -section:system.applicationHost/sites /[name='%ftpsite%'].ftpServer.directoryBrowse.showFlags:DisplayVirtualDirectories 
appcmd set config -section:system.applicationHost/sites /[name='%ftpsite%'].ftpServer.userIsolation.mode:StartInUsersDirectory 
appcmd set config %ftpsite% /section:system.ftpserver/security/authorization /+[accessType='Allow',permissions='Read',roles='',users='*'] /commit:apphost
appcmd add vdir /app.name:"%ftpsite%/" /path:/path1 /physicalPath:D:\path1
appcmd add vdir /app.name:"%ftpsite%/" /path:/path2 /physicalPath:\\MEDIASERVER\path2
```

В интернете представлены реализации для одной команды, я пробовал прописывать команды в строчку и разделять их `&&` или же `&`, но ничего не вышло, как правило дальше первой строчки не выполняется или же вообще консоль закрывается, не выполнив ничего. Хотел бы увидеть примеры кода.

Comment: Самый простой вариант - создаете программно bat\cmd файл, потом запускаете его.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можете использовать несколько решений.

**Первое:**

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe /C \"команда 1.&& команда 2 && команда 3\" ");
```

**Второе:**

```
File.WriteAllText("./somescript.bat",
"команда1\n"+
"команда2\n");
Process.Start("./somescript.bat");й
```

Comment: а зачем *формировать* батник средствами [tag:c#]?, ведь намного проще создать батник с необходимыми командами и его запускать из приложения

Comment: Вдруг ему нужен батник с разными командами?

Comment: в таком случае я думаю должно быть два батника: изменился набор команд, поправили батник/батники, и все работает а в вашем случае надо будет делать *build* приложения. но это так сказать мои придирки

Comment: Не обязательно.

Comment: Достаточно получить новые команды и записать их в файл.

Comment: ваш первый вариант запускает *cmd* и передает команды на выполнение, второй вариант в батник пишет команды, который потом запускается, что бы работало как вы говорите, 2 вариант надо *слегка* изменить, иначе батник всегда будет перезаписываться из кода *приложения*.